# What is the name of the form of dakhisna kali that is seen in the copulating position

Tags: kali

We often come across this form of dakṣiṇa kālī:-

> [image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUVKD.jpg)

The one below her is kālabhairava, and both kālabhairava and kālī is on top of Shiva. It is said that this is the "highest form" of dakṣiṇa kālī, but what is the name of this form?

**Note: Image is hidden for some reason, hover to view.**

EDIT 1: This is to point out, that unlike the comment, which says that there is no such kali, and it is just some artistic fascination. I would like to mention this [picture](https://twitter.com/NMnewdelhi/status/691231109430927364/photo/1) from the 17th century bronze kali, as posted by the national museum.

EDIT 2: some comment mentions that, this is a bhairavi sadhana in some tantrik tradition, and there is no such form of kali. I would like to point out that kali is a Tantrik devi and there is no kali otherwise. And by this [thread](https://www.quora.com/I-saw-a-picture-of-Kali-in-a-copulating-position-with-two-bodies-underneath-her-what-is-the-name-of-this-form-What-are-the-two-bodies-underneath-her/all_comments/Ramkrishna-Sitaraman?comment_id=134114448&comment_type=2&__filter__=all&__nsrc__=1&__sncid__=4594187117&__snid3__=7441110237), one can clearly see that this is not a bhairavi sadhana.

Comment: There is no Goddess as such. It is the form one should take to do bhairavi sadhana. These kind of pictures are done by Westerners who may not know/understand Tantra completely; and hence it becomes misleading for others.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto 17th century dakshina kali https://twitter.com/NMnewdelhi/status/691231109430927364/photo/1

Comment: Like I told you earlier, That's a form of Bhairavi Sadhana, not a Goddess. Sharing a sculpture of 17th century won't make any difference. Tantra is one of the oldest and secret doctrine, by mere seeing a sculpture or image one can not understand it.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, first you bring the Westerner bogeyman into the conversation. Once OP demonstrated this representation is indigenous you muddy the waters with talk of Tantra. What has an understanding of Tantra got to do with the OP's question? He simply seeks to know the name of this form

Comment: @iruvar there is no such form of devi like the OP asking. If you read my comment properly, I mentioned clearly that's a posture one has to take to do bhairavi sadhana. About the drawing, it is true that is done by westerners since the sAdhakas of Tantra are not allowed to reveal secret doctrine.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto you have a lot to learn, check the link of the next edit. I can provide more if you are still not convinced.

Comment: @souparno Dear! I'll say this again that picture you shared is a sadhana method which is called bhairavi sadhana which is done for 4 devis mainly Kali , tara, chinnamasta, bhairavi. The picture represent how this sadhana is done. The picture is not about devi at all. In the second edit link, you saw right how the poster was reluctant to share anything further. :-)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto if that is so, then why does he mention that she is the highest form of dakshina kali and the name of the "form" is secret? https://www.quora.com/I-saw-a-picture-of-Kali-in-a-copulating-position-with-two-bodies-underneath-her-what-is-the-name-of-this-form-What-are-the-two-bodies-underneath-her/answer/Ramkrishna-Sitaraman

Comment: @souparnomajumder Devi is beyond our perception. Why he said that he should tell.

Comment: If you answer the question why her two right hands are empty and what could the left hands symbolize, on a day that "You" are pure, in thought mind and "Axon",  if you know what I mean ...I will attempt :-)

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman the left symbolises destruction of oneself, to offer one to devi, to remove the ego, and the right assures the devote to not get scared in that path of self offering.

Comment: Remove Ego.Correct.Shiva is still and pinned for Pro-Creation. You know without copulation there is no Creation( Before the Modern sperm banks and such...) . Now the question arises what is being attempted for procreation? 'Yoni' also refers to Female reproductive organ. In Tantric circles that is venerated. I mean literally. They have extensive rituals to decorate 'that' in exalted state and copulate later..Source: Para-Trisika Vivarana (Kashmiri Saivism) pg 30+ Why? Think about it assuming there are just 3 humans beings in the whole world. We should move this to chat. Her Grace - mandatory.

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman are you there in the chatroom?